# php: accessing a value from a returned associative array

Tags: php

I have a function `getStatus()` that returns an associative array.

Right now I'm accessing a value with two commands:

```
$a = $user->getStatus();
$a = $a['keyName'];
doSomething($a);
```

Is there a way to rephrase that into one command like:

```
doSomething($user->getStatus()['keyName']);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php access array value from function return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875163/php-access-array-value-from-function-return). In other words: No, that's not possible with the current PHP syntax. Unfortunately, there's no especially concise way to use an element of an array a function returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately that doesn't work.

However, if the order of the returned elements is fixed, you could write something like

```
list($a) = array_values($user->getStatus());
```

Or you could write a function that returns an array value:

```
$a = my_array_value($user->getStatus(),'keyName');
```